# Crash when using Biometric API on some devices

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

We use `androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1` in our application, and on some devices we get an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

at androidx.biometric.fingerprintDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(FingerPrintDialogFragment.java:199)
```

Code on this line is

```
subtitleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

How can we solve this problem? We also tried to use alpha release, but problem still available

Comment: I recommend that you [file an issue against the Biometric library](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:559537), with a sample project that reproduces the crash and the details of what specific device models are triggering the crash.

Comment: The fingerprint dialog varies a lot depending on the device. Probably the subtitleView is not present on some devices... Try to put an if statement and check if the line of code causing the error is applicable on those devices.